# When app goes in background state client disconnected from openTok session - React Native

Tags: react-native, session, opentok

`connectionDestroyed` event being triggered when the app goes into the background and client is disconnecting with session. However, session is still alive. So here, my question is that how can i reconnect client with existing session in openTok react native.

Comment: is this on both platforms? you may need to enable background modes on iOS

Comment: @abdulajet currently its only happens on Android. Whenever app goes in background client disconnected from session. when app comes in active state, client not connected with existing session?

Comment: can you try removing the publisher view and readding it when the client becomes active? you might need to use a Foreground Service to stop the call disconnecting in the first place https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/issues/402#issuecomment-1162737877

Comment: @abdulajet is there any way to implement opentok session in background on react native.